# How to disable certain pop up when typing?

Tags: javascript, popup, visual-studio-code

When writing code in Visual Studio Code, these kind of things keep popping up:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vewi.png)

I would be really grateful if someone could tell me how to disable these as they keep obstructing my code and aren't very useful to me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to disable "IntelliSense"

Comment: @jonSG How do I do that? There doesn't seem to be an option in the config file.

Comment: I don't use VS Code, but here were instruction for howto in VS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecfczya1(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's the suggestion box. It's part of Visual Studio Code's ["IntelliSense" functionality](https://johnpapa.net/intellisense-witha-visual-studio-code/).

If you find it annoying (some people do), you can disable it using the following steps:

1. Open [your settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace#_settings-file-locations). (**Pro Tip**: Open the "Quick Open" interface using the `Ctrl/Cmd + P` keyboard shortcut, and insert "`> Open User Settings`", then press enter. This will open your settings file in Visual Studio Code)
2. Add the `"editor.quickSuggestions"` property to your settings file.
3. Give the [previously added] `"editor.quickSuggestions"` property a value of `false`.

And that's really all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks for this - that's gotten rid of the pop up, but also everything else. I like the quick suggestions, I just didn't want that grey box popping up. I guess it's either all or nothing :(

Comment: @Constantin, the grey box is called the "Quick Suggestion" box, thus turning it off, is going to get rid of the quick suggestions. So yes, unfortunately, as of now, you have to pick between one or the other.